# Автоматическое восстановление процесса

Tags: c, процесс, linux

Допустим есть программа на С. Запускаем ее, и если она крашится, то нужно немедленно запустить ее снова. Подскажите каким образом это сделать

Comment: Зависит от программы и того, что Вы называете "крашится".

Comment: Правильный способ — выпилить всю `unsafe` логику в отдельный процесс, `fork'атьcя` или `spawn'ить` новый процесс / процессы и совершать работу в них. Основной процесс при этом может `poll'ить` эти отдельные процессы (ну или делать что-то чуть более умное) и рестартить их в случае крэшей.

Answer (score 3):

Мы импользуем вариант через inittab. Пример применения (для system V):

```
process:3:respawn:/opt/bin/our_respawining_process
```

Для system.d немного отличается. Создаем конфиг в /etc/init/
Приведу пример для запуска uwsgi

```
# file: /etc/init/uwsgi_project-prod.conf
description "uWSGI server for project-production"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

# This is where you stipulate which set of settings in your ini file you will use.
# You could specify "production" at the end of this command instead of "development" to use a different configuration setup in your ini file.
exec /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.ini:production
```

Answer (score 1):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) например - висит демоном и раз в минуту проверяет, есть ли такой-то процесс, если нет, запускает его снова.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как вариант - в обработчиках ошибок в коде используйте системный вызов [exec](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=exec&category=3&russian=0).